# Use rapply to character vector of suffixes from a character vector of names

Tags: r, apply

I would like to remove a set of suffixes from a set of full names (both suffixes and full names are character vectors). This is pretty easy with two `for()` loops and `gsub()`, but it seems that there should be a more efficient approach (both in lines of code and clock cycles).

My first thought was `rapply()`, but I can't get it to work. Maybe the `for()` loop is the best approach, but at this point I'm interested in better understanding `rapply()`

Here's the `for()` loop version.

```
names.full <- c("tom inc", "dick co", "harry incorp", "larry inc incorp", "curly", "moe")
suffix <- c("inc", "incorp", "incorporated", "co", "company")
suffix <- paste(" ", suffix, "$", sep = "")

# with loops
names.abbr <- names.full
for (k in seq(2)) {
    for (i in seq(length(names.abbr))) {
        for (j in seq(length(suffix))) {
            names.abbr[i] <- gsub(suffix[j], "", names.abbr[i])
        }
    }
}
```

And my failed `rapply()` version.

```
# with rapply
inner.fun <- function(y, x) {
    rapply(as.list(x), function(x) gsub(y, "", x), how = "replace")
}
names.abbr.fail <- unlist(rapply(as.list(suffix), inner.fun, x = names.full, how = replace))
```

Which gives the following error:

```
> names.abbr.fail <- unlist(rapply(as.list(suffix), inner.fun, x = names.full, how = replace))
Error in match.arg(how) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

Comment: The error is I think because you haven't quoted "replace" in your `inner.fun`. Not sure how to do this with `rapply`, but I'm sure there's a better way than the for loops...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you only end up removing all but the first word. That's easily done with

```
sub(" .*$", "", names.full)
```

But a more general regexpr pattern is something like `"(suffix1|suffix2)"` that has ALL your suffixes.

Since you seem to want to remove multiple suffixes from one string as in `"larry inc incorp"`, you need something like `"( suffix1| suffix2)+$"`.

Then you can simply apply it to `names.full` (I changed "moe" into "moe money" to show something where the "first word" solution fails). It would look something like this:

```
names.full <- c("tom inc", "dick co", "harry incorp",
  "larry inc incorp", "curly", "moe money")
suffix <- c("inc", "incorp", "incorporated", "co", "company")

pattern <- paste("(", paste(" ", suffix, collapse="|", sep=""), ")+$", sep="")    
sub(pattern, "", names.full)
[1] "tom"       "dick"      "harry"     "larry"     "curly"     "moe money"
```

And by the way, if you don't want to replace anything but the suffix, `sub` is probably a better fit than `gsub` (`gsub` is typically used to replace *several instances* of a pattern within a word).

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use the for loops? I think you should be able to use back references in gsub to extract what you want.

- The `\\w` matches any character in the range 0 - 9, A - Z and a - z.
- The `+` matches the previous character 1 or more times.
- The `()` allow us    to back reference whatever is inside later in
  the regex.
- The `.`    matches any character all characters and `*` matches the
  preceding    character 0 or more times.

Putting all of the above together gives us:

```
gsub("(\\w+)(.*)", "\\1", names.full)

> gsub("(\\w+)(.*)", "\\1", names.full)
[1] "tom"   "dick"  "harry" "larry" "curly"  "moe"
```

Comment: This works for the given example names, but simply keeps the first word. It would not work on a string like `'moe money inc'`.

Comment: @Tommy - fair point, though from reading through the OP original question and example, that's what he seemingly wanted. Robust solutions should really come with robust examples :) +1 for your answer.